# Does the "promote_users" capability allow someone to create a new admin account?

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I've created a "Second Administrator" role to avoid the worst case scenario happening on my WordPress site when I have casual web development contractors. However if I give them the 'promote_users' capability, can they promote a random user to an Admin and then circumvent the limitations in place?

Comment: In general, casual contractors shouldn't have access to your production site. Let them only have an access to a "sandbox", at most, but you should consider the various local/q&a/staging/production developement methods available out there.

Comment: The scale of this project does not warrant multiple development environments. We do have a careful system for backups online and offline, and one day of downtime would not be highly detrimental.

Comment: @birgire plus, a lot (from my humble experience) clients ask for WP specifically just because they want to be able to add/remove/edit content themselves afterwards, so, it's rather easy to say that, but not practical at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you assign 'promote_users' to another user, that user could promote non-site admins to site admin.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#promote_users

Comment: Thank you for answering the question in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#promote_users):

> - Enables the "Change role to..." dropdown in the admin user list. This
>
>   - does not depend on 'edit_users' capability.

So it would appear that yes, a casual contractor could promote a random user to an administrator, but you may be missing the point:

**If someone is doing development work on your site and they have any of the following access or permissions they can (should they be so inclined)  own your site**:

- FTP access with write permissions
- Remote database access
- cPanel or other hosting access
- WordPress user access at Editor level or above
- A whole bunch of individual permissions including, but not limited to:

  - `edit_files`
  - `install_plugins`
  - `unfiltered_html`

So choose your freelancers with care!